# py2exe, problems

Tags: python, py2exe

I tried all the steps in this [tutorial](http://logix4u.net/Python/Tutorials/How_to_create_Windows_executable_exe_from_Python_script.html).

Yet I keep geting this ouput

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.
```

when I run

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

in command prompt

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`python.exe` is missing in your path. Try to reinstall Python with admin rights or manually add C:\PythonXX\ to your path.

Comment: Remember to close and re-open the command prompt too after setting the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Close and re-open the command prompt not always works, best is to re-login to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just type out the full path to Python in the command prompt:

```
c:\pythonXX\python.exe setup.py py2exe
```

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to e and it was making me soo mad

what i did was go to Start>run and run C:\Python27\python setup.py py2exe

and if your setup.py is in your python directory it should work

Answer (score 0):

the above answer should work but its sometimes especially on a computer with locked down privileges that don't let you mess with path to just use a batch script or even a gui such as [GUI2EXE](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fgui2exe%2F&ei=NluNTMv0AszBcdnK8awE&usg=AFQjCNG50bfJer1un7J_PbJSX5EzBeksrg&sig2=n9ZcN5SJD7mD07IMOq4nXg)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Windows, go to:

```
start > control panel > system and security > system >advanced system settings
```

Now click environment variables, then the `new` button under system variables. Set the variable name to `PATH`(yes, caps. No quotes) and the value to the path of the Python folder under which Python is installed. For me, for example, it is `C:\python27`.

However, if the installation was user specific it will look more like `C:\USER\python27`. USER is, of course, filled in with your user account's name.

The number after the name `python` as the path value will be determined by the version of Python you have.